# How to use Spinning or Wait icon when AsyncTask is being performed in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have used AsyncTask to retrieve data from my web services. I want to show some Spinning or Wait Icon masking while webservice is being processed. I have seen some solutions regarding this but they are very lengthy to write, my requirement is not to show how much percentage is left for complete processing, i just want to show an icon on processing the web service and it should dismiss when it is executed. I am calling this code from my activity and i want to show icon on my activity. See my code below. Please suggest some small and easy solution.

```
public class AsyncLoginWarden extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {


     protected String doInBackground(String...str) {

         WebserviceCall wb = new WebserviceCall();
         wb.param1 = str[0];
         wb.param2 = str[1];
         String response = wb.LoginWarden("LoginWarden");


         return response;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          System.out.println("Successfully logged in."+result);  
     }

}
```

Updated Code

```
package com.example.trafficviolationreporter;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class AsyncLoginWarden extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    Context co;
    MainActivity ma;
    String username, password;

    public AsyncLoginWarden(MainActivity ma, String username, String password) {
        this.ma = ma;
        this.co = ma;
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
        pd = new ProgressDialog(co);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.pd.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... str) {

        WebserviceCall wb = new WebserviceCall();
        wb.param1 = str[0];
        wb.param2 = str[1];
        String response = wb.LoginWarden("LoginWarden");

        return response;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        System.out.println("Successfully logged in." + result);
        pd.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: show the `ProgressDialog` on `onPreExecute()` of AsycTask and then `dismiss()` it in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: progress dialog or you can use animation drawable class. to animate images you want .its very sort n sweet. start anim on pre execution n stop it on post execution. simple

Answer (score 1):

You can create the progress dialog in preexcecute of your async class and dismiss in onpostexecute of async class. Here is how you will do this:

```
public class AsyncLoginWarden extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        ProgressDialog pd;
        Context co;
        YourActivity ma;
        String username, password;

        public AsyncLoginWarden(YourActivity ma, String username, String password) {
            this.ma = ma;
            this.co = ma;
            this.password = password;
            this.username = username;
            pd = new ProgressDialog(co);
            pd.setTitle("title");
            pd.setMessage("message");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.pd.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... str) {

            WebserviceCall wb = new WebserviceCall();
            wb.param1 = str[0];
            wb.param2 = str[1];
            String response = wb.LoginWarden("LoginWarden");

            return response;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            System.out.println("Successfully logged in." + result);
            pd.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

call your async class from activity:

```
YourActivity ma = this;
new AsyncLoginWarden(ma,username,password).execute();
```

Comment: Make sure pd is inside of class scope, and do i need to write any thing special in my Activity, as i have called it like

alw.execute(username,password);

Comment: updated my answer according to your wish. You need to send the activity as well, just a small change to call your async class

Comment: i copied your solution, code is executing but no dialog or wheel is appearing on my UI.

Comment: I am running the same code and I am always using AsyncTask class and this is working flawlessly. Can you put your latest code in your question?

Comment: Class is running correctly, login is also working, but no wheel or spinning is appearing on screen.

Comment: it is just empty classical progress dialogue, nothing fancy. But still it is working for me. Unless you provide what your wrote in your code, can't assist you.

Comment: May be it is executing so fast that you can't see any progressdialog. write these as well in your initialisation so may be you ll be able to catch it easier.                pd.setTitle("title");
                pd.setMessage("message");

Comment: I have written my code below the heading "Updated Code"

Comment: I still think it is because of high speed background process. I pasted it, commented the background part, and it is working for me. Are you calling exactly same as this?    MainActivity ma = MainActivity.this;
    new AsyncLoginWarden(ma,"name","pw").execute();

Comment: I dont think it is high speed because when i click on login it waits for like 3 to 4 seconds, but no wheel or spinning occurs, can you paste the screenshot of your running app with this code?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/CkUHNgT.png?1 took screenshots both with title/message and without them. It is working.

Comment: i am checking on other forums, why process dialog is not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51357/discussion-between-muhammad-atif-agha-and-sir-sc)

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog pDialog;
public class AsyncLoginWarden extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

        }
     protected String doInBackground(String...str) {

         WebserviceCall wb = new WebserviceCall();
         wb.param1 = str[0];
         wb.param2 = str[1];
         String response = wb.LoginWarden("LoginWarden");


         return response;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          System.out.println("Successfully logged in."+result);  

          if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
     }

}
```

The above code will show a `ProgressDialog` during the background task and will dismiss it when the background task is completed.

Comment: My code is executing but i dont see any progress dialog on my view while application is running.

Comment: @MuhammadAtifAgha: did you got any error or exception ? This code is 100% correct and I use it in almost every `AsyncTask` code.

Comment: i did not get any exception, just i want is to show the spinning icon of android while processing.

Comment: @MuhammadAtifAgha: do you see the `println` statement of `onPostExecute()` in the logcat ?

Comment: I have put a Toast.Make in PreExecute. And now i noticed it is appearing after the processing is done, means when logged in and moved to next screen then it appeared.